# How to align two input texts on a line in Materialize?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I would like to center two input texts on Materialize.css, but the results are not good when i try to do that. That's the code:

```
<div class="card-content valign center">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                    <input id="Valor1" type="text" class="validate" maxlength="10">
                    <label for="Valor1">Valor 1</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                    <input id="Valor2" type="text" class="validate" maxlength="10">
                    <label for="Valor2">Valor 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here there is a lot of text fields for example: [Materalize Text Fields](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html)

Comment: When you say the results are not good, what exactly are you seeing?

Comment: The two input texts stay on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center the  inputs you can add [offsets](https://materializecss.com/grid.html#grid-offsets) to your first column:

```
<div class="input-field col s3 offset-s3">
    <input id="Valor1" type="text" class="validate" maxlength="10">
    <label for="Valor1">Valor 1</label>
</div>
```

The entire length of your row is 12 columns. Your two inputs have a total of 6 columns. With an offset of 3 columns on the left you get your desired centering of your elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot ikkuh. Exactly what i was searching for.